# saving a PORT as static const member

Tags: c++, static, avr, static-members, avr-gcc

How do i store a `PORT` or `DDR` or such as static const member?
What i am trying todo is, instead of using `#define TEMPERATURE_PORT PORTC` inside of my class header i would like to store a static const member with that value and iniziallise this inside of a settings.h to have all my defines at one place.

```
class Temperatur
{
private:
    static const volatile uint8_t m_port;
};
```

settings.h which gets included last

```
const uint8_t Temperatur::m_port = PORTC;
```

This acutally causes the

```
Error   24  'Temperatur::m_port' cannot be initialized by a non-constant expression when being declared
```

---

I use the assignement is inside of the settings.h which get included right after that file:

```
#include "Sensors/Temperatur.h"
#include "Sensors/Microphone.h"
//... some more includes here
//load the static and const settings
#include "settings.h"
```

This does already work for some other values but not for `PORT` and `DDR`.

Some more information:
The Port is defined as:

```
#define PORTC _SFR_IO8(0x08)
```

which is defined as:

```
#define _SFR_IO8(io_addr) ((io_addr) + __SFR_OFFSET)
```

And this is a fixed value since the __SFR_OFFSET is defined as 0x00 or 0x20 depending on some marko value.

Is it maybe the definition of the makro for the `_SFR_IO8` because it has a simple calculation? If so how do i solve this?

Comment: what type is `PORTC`? In which file are you assigning it to `m_port`?

Comment: `PORTC` is defined as `_SFR_IO8(0x08)` and i assign it to `m_port` inside of a `settings.h` which i include in the main file right after including the other parts of the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compiles fine for me:

```
#define __SFR_OFFSET 0x00
#define _SFR_IO8(io_addr) ((io_addr) + __SFR_OFFSET)
#define PORTC _SFR_IO8(0x08)

class Temperatur
{
private:
    static const volatile uint8_t m_port;
};

const volatile uint8_t Temperatur::m_port = PORTC;
```

---

The only thing that I found you might be missing is the `volatile` keyword in the assignment.

Comment: yes right. Thats it i missed the volatile. Thanks on that i didnt see it.